# Understanding Why Adding an Arbitrary Integral to a Function is Required?

Tags: probability, integration

I am going over the notes on this website (https://xiuming.info/docs/tutorials/reml.pdf) and trying to understand the integral on page 5:

$$L_w(\theta | A^Ty) = \log f_w(A^Ty | \theta)$$

\begin{aligned}
&= \log f_w(A^Ty|\theta) \\
&\int f_{\hat{\beta}}(\hat{\beta}|\beta,\theta) d\hat{\beta}
\end{aligned}

$$= \log f_w(A^Ty|\theta) \ \int f_{\hat{\beta}}(G^Ty|\beta,\theta) d\beta$$

**My Question:** In the second step, I am trying to understand why the integral $\int f_{\hat{\beta}}(\hat{\beta}|\beta,\theta) d\hat{\beta}
$ appears all of a sudden.

My guess is that $\int f_{\hat{\beta}}(\hat{\beta}|\beta,\theta) d\hat{\beta}$ is likely equal to $1$, therefore adding it to the existing term from step 1 will not change anything, and this addition might be a "strategic step" in performing further manipulations.

However, I am still not sure why it is necessary to add $\int f_{\hat{\beta}}(\hat{\beta}|\beta,\theta) d\hat{\beta}
$ to the previous step and what exactly this accomplishes.

Can someone please help me understand this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

$f_\hat\beta(\hat\beta)$ is a probability distribution, so $\int f_\hat{\beta}(\hat\beta) d\hat\beta=1$. He adds that term so he can throw more stuff into the integral, combine it, and do some fancy manipulations.

Comment: @ Eric: thank you for your answer! But why precisely $\int f_\beta d\beta=1$ ? A lot of integrals equal 1 - why was $\int f_\beta d\beta=1$ chosen?